# Gmail API ? how to request for an email using Gmail api with format of raw and how to convert it into normal String

Tags: java, gmail-api

Can anybody help me out in this? I'm working with [[image]gmail-api](/questions/tagged/gmail-api) where I need to read a email. I have gone through the documentation of Gmail API for reading a messages, and I'm able to read email into RFC format. How do I convert it to normal Text?

If at all I need to use Java Libraries Mime classes for conversion, how do I use it specifically to read "From address", "To address" and "Message Body?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have a raw (RFC822) email string you can use the java `MimeMessage` library to parse it and then read the headers.  I found a couple by searching for `java MimeMessage example`.  You can use the `MimeMessage(Session, InputStream)` constructor, once you have a `MimeMessage` you can just call things like `getFrom()` or `getHeader(String headerName)` on it.

While not exactly what you're trying to do, the Gmail API java guide for *sending* email is somewhat relevant in that it shows how to deal with MimeMessage libraries, etc:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending

Comment: But there are two getHeaders() methods in which one returns array of objects and another getHeader("Header name","delimiters"). which one i should use ? if i prefer the second method what should be in the place of delimiters.

Comment: I suppose it's a preference and depends on which headers you want.  For from I'd use just "getFrom()" and for To/Cc you can use "getAllRecipients()" which does the extra parsing and provides you with a parsed Address field.  For other headers, I'd personally just use getHeader(headerName) form and check the array, in many cases you probably only expect one of the header (like Message-Id, List-Id, Sender, etc) so you can check it's ".length == 1"